# how to display 3rd party software in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

**OS :** Ubuntu
**SDK :** Qt 5.5.0
**Issue:**
I have to add 3rd party server utility and receive utility in my Qt project. 3rd party software is open source project which I have configured compiled and built in my Ubuntu system.
 So Like normal utility I go into installed directory path and type something like sudo ./server_start and it starts server. Similarly if I do sudo ./receive , then receive utility get started and it waits infinitely for message to arrive. whenever remote utility sends message it get displayed in ubuntu terminal.

Everything is good so far.
 Now I want in Qt to start 3rdpaty application using button and message if come get stored somewhere so that my other Qt functions looks for particular keyword in it and parse it properly.

To start 3rd party application I can include something like sudo ./server_start in button_clicked slot.
My problem is how would I store message in some data structure or display in QtextEdit? Since message just displayed in stdout in terminal.
So in summary my issue is :
 1) How to avoid message getting displayed in terminal when i Start sudo "./receive" but get store in file or in data structure for further parsing by other functions.
2) Is including command like " sudo ./server_started is right way of doing in Qt? How about if I change 3rd party source code and then some how linked it in my project? What are adv and disadvantages?

Comment: Have a look at [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#details)

Comment: Can you use the 3rd party software as a library instead?

Comment: Yes. I guess so. I have its source code written in C so I can include it in my project. I am wondering which one is better approach? using Qprocess or include 3rd party source code?